# Define A Range Of Numbers in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, range

Is there a way that I could divide a range of numbers into certain sub ranges

i.e.
If we have the range 1-10

The user inputs 1 3 , 4 7 ,7 10
and we define the range 1-3 as part of one range, 4-7 as another and so on.
and if inputed the number 8 for example, we get output as range 3.

Was considering creating an array **int arr[10]** and as user inputs 1 3 for eg then arr[0]=1 and arr[2]=1 , then for 4 7 as arr[3]=2 and arr[6]=2 . But this misses numbers in between and if  we looped from 0 to 2,and 3 to 6. On a larger scale with an array longer than 10 this would be inefficient.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Is this question related to C, C++ or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a range type:

```
struct range
{
  int low;
  int high;
}
```

Then define an array of such:

```
struct range ranges[<some size>] = {0};
```

Define and implement functions finding the highest `high` and the lowest lowest `low` values:

```
int lowest(struct range * ranges, int * plowest);
int highest(struct range * ranges, int * phighest);
```

Enter all ranges and stores them in `ranges`.

Call `highest()` and `lowest()` on `ranges` and you have the outer interval:

```
struct range range_outer = {0};

/* code reading ranges. */

if (0 != lowest(ranges, &range_outer.lowest))
  fprintf(stderr, "lowest() failed\n");

if (0 != highest(ranges, &range_outer.highest))
  fprintf(stderr, "highest() failed\n");
```

To help `lowest()` and `highest()` it might make sense to sort the `ranges`, by member `low` for the former by member `high` for the latter.

```
int sort_by_low(struct ranges * ranges); 
int sort_by_high(struct ranges * ranges);
```

Sorting arrays can easily be done by using the [`qsort()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

A full working implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    int min; int max; int range;
} RANGE;

int InRange(int num, RANGE range)
{
    if (num >= range.min && num <= range.max)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    vector<RANGE> list; int count = 0, rangesCount = 0;
    puts("How many ranges?");
    cin >> rangesCount;
    puts("Input the range defenitions as a min-max-range pairs(Enter min, then enter      max, then enter the output range):");
for (int i = 0; i < rangesCount; i++)
{
    RANGE range;
    cin >> range.min;
    cin >> range.max;
    cin >> range.range;
    list.push_back(range);
}

while (1)
{
    puts("Now, enter a value, to know in what range it exist:");
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    for (int i = 0; i < rangesCount; i++)
    {
        RANGE r = list.at(i);
        int included = InRange(num, r);
        if (included)
        {
            cout << "The output range is " << r.range << "\n\n";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Many things can be improved, and you can tailor it to your needs.

Comment: This may not help if these values are meant to be defined in runtime. You would need a proper data structure to describe the subranges.

Comment: OP mentioned that the user would input the range definitions, so there you go.

Comment: We are talking C here.

Comment: @alk the OP says exactly "C/C++" in the title.

Comment: Ups, yes, the title says, the tags don't. Missed to fully scroll up, sry, my bad.

Comment: Not a problem. Although OP should stick to mentioning one of the two in the tags. :)

Comment: A nice -1 for `typedef struct` utilizing C++

Comment: Another -1 would be the unchecked `cin >> num;`

Comment: @DieterLücking you're not asking me to check for errors and such in a code showing a working implementation for reference purposes, are you?
And making a class is an overkill for the same purposes.

Comment: @mr992 Sure I do. Have all tests making the code 'working' (no need for elaborated error reporting)

Comment: @DieterLücking It works. It shows how to obtain the needed result the OP asked for. What should be added is just the checking, I'm not providing this for a copy-paste you know.

Comment: @mr992 `cin >> 'a'` and your code is using an uninitialized `num`

Comment: @DieterLücking once again, there's nothing wrong with minimal checking (even none) in such cases for well known reasons, even top books do that, because we want to present the idea (and the solution) with minimal distraction. And once again, the code is not intended for a lowly copy-paste.